# Determine possible isomorphic types of H given G and the existence of an epimorphism G -> H

Tags: group-theory

I've been going through old assignments and found this one I couldn't figure out:

Let $H$ be a group. Let there be an epimorphism $f: G \to H$. Now, given different groups $G$, determine all possible isomorphic types for $H$.

I don't understand how to do this in principle. I believe I remember that $H$ need to be isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$ so the task would be to determine all normal subgroups, but I couldn't figure out a proof for why that would be the case (it seems that $H$ must be isomorphic to $G / ker(f)$ and $ker(f)$ must be normal in $G$, but that's not sufficient). I'd like to know why this holds, or if it doesn't, what other criteria there is.

(I don't believe the different values for G are relevant for this question, but just in case, they were $D_8, D_{10}, Q_8, A_4$)

Comment: Your arrows are not consistent in your title and your body. Please fix it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: apologies, fixed. I'll also remember how to use the more pretty looking formatting in the future.

Comment: Yes, either by the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem or First Isomorphism Theorem (whatever you name it), $H$ must be iso to a quotient of $G$.  Because of this, it absolutely matters what the "value" of $G$ is.

Comment: It is not true that $H$ must be isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$. It is isomorphic to a quotient group of $G$.

Comment: ^ okay, that in essence answers the question. I can see how you prove that, too. thanks.